# Query without full data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query

```sql
SELECT
  U.Country,
  U.Product,
  Week,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN Year = 2022
    THEN SoldUnits ELSE 0 END
  ) AS TotalSoldUnits
FROM Uploads U
INNER JOIN MaxWeek_Product T1
ON T1.Product = U.Product
  AND MaxWeek = Week
where U.country = 'GT'
GROUP BY U.Country, U.Product
ORDER BY U.Country;
```

It returns me something like this:

| Country | Product | Week | TotalSoldUnits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GT | ABC003 | 7 | 245 |
| GT | ABC403 | 8 | 255 |
| GT | ABC073 | 7 | 145 |
| GT | ABCb03 | 10 | 240 |

The problem is that It has to return 500 rows and actually returns 480 rows.
I found that the problems is in `AND MaxWeek = Week` because some `Products` has `Week = 0` in the table `MaxWeek_Product` but in the `Uploads` table, none of the `Products` have `Week = 0`. And those `Products` get lost in the `INNER JOIN`.

I tried using `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` but still, it doesn't work.

What can I do to retrieve those missing `Products` with `TotalSoldUnits = 0`.

Uploads table:

| Country | Product | Week | SoldUnits | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GT | ABC003 | 7 | 245 | 2022 |
| GT | ABC403 | 8 | 255 | 2022 |
| GT | ABC073 | 7 | 145 | 2022 |
| GT | ABCb03 | 10 | 240 | 2022 |
| GT | OBCb03 | 16 | 128 | 2021 |

MaxWeek_Product table:

| Country | Product | MaxWeek |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GT | ABC003 | 7 |
| GT | ABC403 | 8 |
| GT | ABC073 | 7 |
| GT | ABCb03 | 10 |
| GT | ACb037 | 0 |

Comment: Just switch the tables. Do a from Maxwell_products and left join the uploads

Comment: The `Uploads` table doesn't contain the `Year` field: you're referencing this field in the `CASE` statement. Can you check? @NHW

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. I forgot to put it in the example.

Comment: You're picking a random week from each group, since you don't have `Week` in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: When you use `LEFT JOIN`, put conditions on the second table in the `ON` clause, not `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is the `WHERE` statement, because it activates after the `JOIN` operations have taken effect, hence removing the rows that the `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN` could have saved (with `NULL` values).

Here is how it becomes after the changes:

```
SELECT T1.Country,
       T1.Product,
       T1.MaxWeek,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Year = 2022 THEN SoldUnits ELSE 0 END) AS TotalSoldUnits
FROM      MaxWeek_Product T1
LEFT JOIN Uploads U
       ON T1.Product = U.Product
      AND T1.MaxWeek = U.Week
      AND T1.country = 'GT'
GROUP BY T1.Country, 
         T1.Product, 
         T1.MaxWeek
ORDER BY T1.Country;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uxtbhS4RZvtheciAkVKe8m/1).

Comment: Thanks! It works for me!